# Seeking API for Rail-route distance

Tags: openstreetmap, software-recommendations, overpass-api, overpass-turbo, railroad

I am new to GIS and looking for a way to get rail route distance between a given origin and destination set (available as names, or city center lat-long for widely used city pairs within europe). SO far I have tired to read through OpenRailwayMap, OpenStreetMap and Overpass Query API, but couldn’t find any way to use them for my purpose.

Can you provide any leads or examples?

I only know Python, and sourcing the distance data is for a Sustainability related project in order to calculate accurate carbon emissions.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Google Directions API and fire off sets of start/end coordinates and ensure mode is set to *transit* and transit_mode is set to *rail*.

You can explore the [API help file](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions) and call the API from a python script. It returns a JSON dictionary object which you can interrogate for distance, total travel time and even the polyline you see displayed on google maps, although that needs decoding.

Answer (score 0):

Graphhopper supports this use case, maybe take a look at https://www.geofabrik.de/projects/railway_routing/index.html and https://github.com/geofabrik/OpenRailRouting